# summer reading suggestions

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, partial-differential-equations, proof-writing

I have just finished 2nd year of my maths degree and I was wondering if anyone had any good recommendations for summer reading, I want to make sure I keep practising so that I don't feel underprepared for next semester.

I am particularly interested in becoming more confident in lineal algebra, abstract algebra and differential equations (including partial), so books with a lot of questions would be great.

One of my biggest issues is proof writing, whenever I try a proof question I never know if it is adequate as textbooks and the university solutions often omit them and I am aware it is a skill i will desperately need next semester. I was wondering if anyone could offer any advice for developing proof skills.

Comment: I really liked Gallian's abstract algebra book as an undergrad. It's quite well-written and actually written appropriately for undergrads. It also has several auxiliary chapters on some applied topics, and some of them can be read independently of the rest of the book.

Comment: Can I clarify, is your difficulty in (1) coming up with the answer to proof-type questions, (2) filling out the details of a proof (but you're usually able to get the general idea), or (3) simply writing and structuring the proof, but not actually solving it?

Comment: For the most part (2) but for a few more challenging questions I usually have no idea how to go about proving it.